# What to dispose when using Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data?

Tags: c#, vb.net, dispose

What I need to Dispose (and destroy) when using `Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data` to avoid leaks?

Actually I'm disposing the `DbCommand` and the `DataSet`:

VB.Net:

```
DataSet = DB.ExecuteDataSet(Command)

'do something ...

Command.Dispose()
Command = Nothing
DataSet.Dispose()
DataSet = Nothing
```

C#:

```
DataSet = DB.ExecuteDataSet(Command);

//do something ...

Command.Dispose();
Command = null;
DataSet.Dispose();
DataSet = null;
```

But is it enough?

Do I need destroy the `SqlDatabase`? What about the `DbConnection`?

Comment: I edited the code. I don't think it's necessary due to the code complexity, but a C# example was included.

Comment: The lazy answer is to dispose of everything that implements IDisposable, and instead of explicitly calling `Dispose` to instead wrap usage in `using` blocks.

Comment: These objects are in a class that implements 'IDisposable'. I want to know what I have to do when call 'Dispose()'. Do I also need to destroy everything?

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: dispose every object that implements `IDisposable` as soon as you don't need it anymore. Use the [`using` statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/htd05whh.aspx) for a safe and short syntax.

Comment: Ok. But do I need to set DB to null after using it? Because the `SqlDatabase` class does not implement IDisposable.